# Подсчитать количество новостей в категории. SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с категориями, `news_cats`, структура: `id | title`, и таблица с новостями, `news` с полем `cat`.
Есть подобный скрипт:

```
SELECT
    news_cats.id,
    news_cats.title,
    COUNT(news.cat) AS c_cats
FROM
news_cats,
news
WHERE 
    news.cat=news_cats.id
ORDER BY
    c_cats DESC
```

Только вот выбирает он не то и не так.
Мне нужны поля `news_cats.id, и news_cats.title`, и после них циферка. Включая ноль.

Comment: В продолжение темы =)

    SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`title`, `t2`.`c_tags` 
        FROM `news_tags` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `tags`, COUNT(*) AS `c_tags` FROM `news` GROUP BY  `tags`) `t2`
    ON `t2`.`tags` LIKE "%`t1`.`id`%"

Циферку не возвращает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`title`, `t2`.`c_cats` 
    FROM `news_cats` `t1`
JOIN (SELECT `cat`, COUNT(*) AS `c_cats` FROM `news` GROUP BY `cat`) `t2`
    ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`cat`
```

Comment: Малюсенькая поправочка - LEFT JOIN, нулевые значения захватить. Спасибо =)